# Find all elements in HTML by XPath expression as array

Tags: javascript, xpath

Is there any way to collect all HTML nodes matches XPath expression as array?

Answer (score 1):

Using Saxon JS 2 (https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml), you can use XPath 3.1 in the browser and could use e.g.

```
SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(xPathExp, document, { resultForm : 'array', 'xpathDefaultNamespace' : 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's code snippet:

```js
function xPathFunct(xPathExp){
    var resXPath = document.evaluate(xPathExp, document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
    var result=resXPath.iterateNext();
    var resArray = [];
    while (result){
        resArray.push(result);
        result=resXPath.iterateNext();
    }
    return resArray;
}
```